# VBA-Excel Vlookup - > Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I hope you can give me some tips on this. I recently got this task to correct cells in a row such as this one:

```
Contact: Address 1
-------------------
16, Shota Rustaveli
241 Mukanov Street
241 Mukaov Street
241 Mukaov Street
241 Mukaov Street
241 Mukaov Street
241 Mukaov Street
241 Muknov Street
3, rue Rene Cassin
3, rue Rene Cassin
9th Floor, South To
AddressLine1
Baribaev str. 31
Danubius utca 16.
Fő út 197.
Homokbánya köz 10.
Mikulandská 122/4
Mikulanská 122/4
```

So, the main idea is if there is one character(special characters two) missing it should be added. So what I did was to use the function Vlookup to look up every cell with its next one and if they are similar to correct the second one and if not to skip it.

```
Private Sub AddressCorrection()

Dim AddCorr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim AddLookup As Variant
Dim wksSource As Worksheet

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With wksSource
For i = 3 To 20
k = i + 1
j = i + 1
AddLookup = wksSource.Range("AQ" & i).Value
    'Check if it is in the same company
    If wksSource.Range("A" & i).Value = wksSource.Range("A" & j).Value Then
    On Error Resume Next
        If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AddLookup, wksSource.Range("AQ" & j), 1, True)) Then
        GoTo EndLine
        Else
           AddCorr = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AddLookup, wksSource.Range("AQ" & k), 1, True)
                   If AddCorr = wksSource.Range("AR" & i).Value Then
                       'Do nothing
                   Else
                       wksSource.Range("AQ" & j).Value = wksSource.Range("AQ" & i).Value
                   End If
        End If
    Else
        GoTo EndLine
    End If
EndLine:
'End of loop
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

The main problem is that on half the items this works correctly as I want it to... but on another half the:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AddLookup, wksSource.Range("AQ" & j), 1, True)
```

Gives me Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

and sometimes I don't even get the error it goes as I want it and after a few changes to the Sheet itself, it gives me the same error.

I am not sure maybe I am addressing the Sheet wrong or some of the objects, or even maybe I haven't understood the Vlookup Function well enough.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Do you definitely want the last Vlookup parameter to be True? I have to confess I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why are you using Vlookup to check the value of a single cell against the value of another single cell ?

Comment: I used to use vlookup in Excel itself to check how close to similar the values are. And since I am new to this part I thought of using it. I used True because I don't want them to be exactly similar but only close to similar. it is not enough to see if Value1==Value2 I need to find those which are close as if only one character is missing and then correct that.

Comment: That's not really what that last argument does?

Comment: it does the job perfectly but not all the time. Example:
241 Mukanov Street
241 Mukaov Street
There is only one letter missing here but i get an error:
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
But if the "M" is missing it works fine and edits it perfectly
I don't know why some times it works and other times it doesn't